# How to edit a file that only exists on the web? (Debian Linux)

Tags: linux, debian, files, minecraft

I play minecraft on an HP Chromebook 14. When I look up, "How to turn up gamma without mods", it tells me to go to ".minecraft" and find a file called "options.txt". I have found it, but it only exists on the web with a url of: "file:///media/fuse/crostini_*[SomeRandomText]*_termina_penguin/.minecraft/options.txt". How do I edit this file, and then save it to minecraft?

Comment: That's a `file://` URI, which means it's referring to a local file somewhere under `/media/fuse/...`, (which might be a mounted [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) filesystem. Or maybe not).  [URIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) don't always point to web resources, it's right there in the name: "Uniform Resource Identifier".

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet. This doesn't seem to be in the web as in the url it doesn't appears any server or ip direction. Try typing in the terminal

```
nano url
```

Replacing url by the url given there staring in /media ...